# array of organizations with a default?

Tags: macros

I am trying to make a custom list, that has a default value, without being dependent on too many other packages because I am trying to get some very specific formatting.  I am trying to use this for a custom coverpage that I hope to put into a custom CLS.  I imagine this as working

```
\organization{2nd organization}
\organization{3rd organization}
\makecustomcover
```

I hope this will render:

```
1st organization
2nd organization
3rd organization
```

Obviously, \makecustomcover will iterate over the values; however, I'm unclear the best way to "push" them into a stack.  I'm also unclear of the best way to have the default one.  Any advice or references that would discuss this would be appreciated.

Comment: you might take a look at `amsart.cls` to see how multiple `\address`es are saved up and set one after another.  it uses a command `\g@addto@macro` (defined in `latex.ltx`) to compile the list, and `\@setaddresses` to output them.  what's done in `amsart` is overkill for your request, but it should show how the process works.

Comment: A small MWE showing the context in which `\makecustomcover` must operate would give us a lot of help in suggesting approaches.  For example, will the addition of organizations push down other text lower on the page, or will it just fill up a previously designated blank space?  Might an organization have a multi-line name, or can one expect each organization to occupy a single line?  Things like that are important considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to use `\g@addto@macro` for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@organization{1st organization\par}
\newcommand\organization[1]{\g@addto@macro\@organization{#1\par}}
\newcommand\makecustomcover{\@organization}
\begin{document}
\organization{2nd organization}
\organization{3rd organization}
\makecustomcover
\end{document}
```

> [image]